# Countif url match regexp

Tags: regex, google-sheets, countif

I have a long list of URLs. I want to find the number of URLs in the list that contain a number between 1 and 9 ( [1-9] ).

How can I do this with a regular expression in Google Spreadsheets?

Answer (score 0):

One way (I doubt the best):

```
=countif(ArrayFormula(iferror(1*regexextract(A1:A,"[1-9]"),0)),">0")
```